# Calculating curvature with numpy, sharp incorrect jumps in curvature at beginning and end of curve?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to calculate curvature values using Numpy, and for the most part using the standard math seems to work well. However, I seem to be running into an issue with the ends of my curve having their curvature calculated incorrectly. Here's an example of what I mean below:

The curve:

[image]

The calculated curvature:

[image]

As you can see, there's two very sharp transitions at the beginning and end of the curvature plot, despite the curve itself not having any such sharp changes in curvature. Would anyone have any idea as to why this might be occurring? I've tested my code on multiple other curves and see similar behavior at the ends.

Here is my code that I use to calculate the curvature for two numpy arrays of x and y points:

```
# Calculate first derivative of spline
dx = np.gradient(spline_x)
dy = np.gradient(spline_y)

# Calculate the second derivative of spline
d2x = np.gradient(dx)
d2y = np.gradient(dy)

# Calculate curvature
spline_curvature = (dx * d2y - d2x * dy) / ((dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 1.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always expect this kind of artifacts.

If you calculate the gradient along a vector using the difference between neighbors, you estimate the gradient in each interval, and the result necessarily has one value less then the original vector:

```
>>> v = np.array([2,1,3,3,4,5,3,4], dtype=float)
>>> len(v)
8
>>> g = np.diff(v)
>>> g
array([-1.,  2.,  0.,  1.,  1., -2.,  1.])
>>> len(g)
7
```

Numpy estimates the [gradient](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) at each point using a better approximation, taking into account the neighbors of each value:

```
>>> (v[2:] - v[:-2])/2
array([ 0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  1. , -0.5, -0.5])
>>> g = np.gradient(v)
>>> g
array([-1. ,  0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  1. , -0.5, -0.5,  1. ])
>>> len(g)
8
```

But, as you can see, the gradient has the same number of elements as the original vector, so the first and last values can't be calculated the same way. In fact they coincide with the first and last values of the former (diff) method. But those were not estimations for points, but for intervals.

So each time you use [gradient](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html), you should discard the first and last elements to avoid such border artifacts.

Comment: Appreciate the response, that clarifies things for me!